# psycopg2 why is the schema not created?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

im trying to create a schema in postgres database using psycopg2.

For some reason the schema is not created and later on the code crashes because it tries to refer to the missing schema. The connection is set to auto commit mode, which definetly works because i can create a database with this specific connection.

For debugging purposes i have wrapped every step in it's own try/except statement.

Code is below, as it is right there, it does not raise any exceptions, just the follow up crashes because the schema is missing.

```
def createDB(dbName, connString):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(connString)
    conn.set_session(autocommit =True) # autocommit must be True sein, else CREATE DATABASE will fail https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#transactions-control
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    createDB = sql.SQL('CREATE DATABASE {};').format(
        sql.Identifier(dbName)
    )

    createSchema = sql.SQL('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema2;')

    searchpath = sql.SQL('ALTER DATABASE {} SET search_path TO public, schema2;').format(
        sql.Identifier(dbName)
    )
    dropDB = sql.SQL('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {};').format(
        sql.Identifier(dbName)
    )

    try:
        cursor.execute(dropDB)
    except Exception as e:
        print('drop DB failed')
        logging.error(e)
        conn.close()
        exit()

    try:
        cursor.execute(createDB)
    except Exception as e:
        print('create DB failed')
        logging.error(e)
        conn.close()
        exit()

    try:
        cursor.execute(createSchema)
        print('schema created')
    except Exception as e:
        print('create schema failed')
        logging.error(e)
        conn.close()
        exit()

    try:
        cursor.execute(searchpath)
    except Exception as e:
        print('set searchpath failed')
        logging.error(e)
        conn.close()
        exit()
    conn.close()
```

Adding an explicit commit does not do the trick either.
What am i missing?

**EDIT**
I have added a small screenshot with the console logs. As you can see, the code below gets executed.

[image: Console screenshot]

**EDIT 2**
Out of sheer curiosity, i have tried to execute this very SQL statement in pgadmin:

`CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema2`

and it works just fine, which shows, that my SQL is not wrong, so back to square one.

**EDIT 3 -- Solution**

So i have come up with a solution, thank to you @jjanes for pointing me in the right direction. This function does not connect to a specific database, but the server as a whole, since im using it to create new databases, hence the connection string looks something like this :

```
user=postgres password=12345 host=localhost port=5432
```

Which allows me to perform server level operations like create and drop database. But schemas are a Database level operation. Moving the exact same logic to the part of the code which is connected to the newly created database works like a charm.

Comment: Just to be sure: Do you call this function in your code?

Comment: yes definitely, because the drop database and the create database statement get executed

Comment: Just to be sure: Does this line show up in console or IDE, `print('schema created')`?

Comment: PostgreSQL can't connect without connecting to a specific database (like MySQL does).  If you specify a username but not a database, then it takes the username as also being the database name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the schema in the original database specified by the connect string.  Once you create the new database, you need to connect to it in order to work in it.  Otherwise, you are just working in the old database.

Comment: thank you, i have edited the question and added an explanation for the issu, but since you pointed me in the right direction im going to accept your answer.